# How can I build a container when every article (height fits content) starts one after another

Tags: css, grid, containers, positioning

It's hard to explain (maybe because of my english) what I'd like to do but like in the title -  I want to do container when every article's height fits the content and article start right after another (vertically).

Here is the example:
http://herballeaf.eu/herbal-blog/

Is it possible to do it with flexbox?

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat hard to know exactly what you mean, but I'm guessing you're referring to wanting 3 different columns each going down the page.
For this I would use a parent container with flex display, and similarly, three divs for the children of the parent container which all have flex display, but instead of having row-direction, they have column (so they go down). Be sure that the parent div(s) have enough height and width to contain them :)
If you want them to "start right after another" then you may want to change the margin :)

```
.parentContainer{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
width: auto; /*be sure that the width is wide enough to contain all three child divs*/
}
.containerOne .containerTwo .containerThree{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
```

Hopefully this is what you're looking for :) I took a stab in the dark with this so apologies if it's wrong

Comment: Sorry for this explaination but you've understood me so success!=D 
Yeaah I thought about these 3 containers technique but forgot to say that I'd like to do it all by only one container if its possible. Anyway thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, the following code will be enough:

```
.parentContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column
}
```